# BlobMesage 401 Unauthorized on ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a problem when creating a blob message to transfer file on ActiveMQ. 
Error: javax.jms.JMSException: PUT was not successful: 401 Unauthorized
Here my brokerURL:

```
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
<property name="brokerURL"><value>tcp://localhost:61616?jms.blobTransferPolicy.defaultUploadUrl=http://localhost:8161/fileserver/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="userName" value="admin" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean>
```

Any issues here ? I spent some hours for searching but not find correct solution. Please share to me

Answer (score 0):

I'd try connecting with the http server with a http/ftp client and verify you have write permissions...

Comment: I have just checked on ActiveMQ 5.7. It's fine. on ActiveMQ 5.8 still this error. There is a difference in ActiveMQ's version. Someone give a solution that i should input username & password in brokerURL but still error. What is format of brokerURL with username & password ?

Comment: I tested with brokerURL: 1. tcp://localhost:61616?jms.blobTransferPolicy.defaultUploadUrl=http://localhost:8161/fileserver/?admin:admin ( error: Invalid connect parameters: {username=admin:password=admin}) 2. tcp://localhost:61616?jms.blobTransferPolicy.defaultUploadUrl=http://localhost:8161/fileserver/?username=admin:password=admin (Invalid connect parameters: {username=admin:password=admin}>) . What is the format for brokerURL ?

Comment: tcp://localhost:61616?jms.blobTransferPolicy.uploadUrl=ftp://ftpuser:password@localhost/

Comment: In my case,this works. with / at the end. Don't know why gets erased

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an HTTP transport connector:

```
<transportConnector name="http" uri="http://0.0.0.0:8080"/>
```

The URI as http://localhost:8080 did **not** work in my case.
I am also under the impression that the default connectors are not secured and username and password are obsolete (at least for a first try).

**Final solution**

ActiveMQ config (activemq.xml)

```xml
    <transportConnectors>
       <transportConnector name="http" uri="http://0.0.0.0:8080"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

Java Client (producer only)

```java
    try {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("http://localhost:8080");
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    // Create a Session
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // Create the best Queue ever
    Destination destination = session.createQueue("STACKOVERFLOW.SUPPORT");

    // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

    // Create a messages
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("I hope, this snippets helps you :D | Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    producer.send(message);

    //clean up
    session.close();
    connection.close();
    } catch(JMSException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```